# How to assign a variable returned from a function

Tags: c, cgi

I'm very much new to C, and I am trying to assign an array that is returned from the decode function after the main to a pointer so that I can use it in my program (e.g. print it). The code compiles, but I get an "error 500" when I run the CGI.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {

printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

char *decode(char *url);

char *qPtr;
char *ePtr;
char *emailClean;

if(qPtr = getenv("QUERY_STRING")) {
  char Buffer[256];
  char *Token;
  char username[80], password[80], email[80];
  strncpy(Buffer, qPtr, 255); //copy Env variable "QUERY_STRING" into qPtr pointer

  Token = strtok(Buffer, "&"); //get first query
  sscanf(Token, "username=%s", username); //gets value of username field input

  Token = strtok(NULL, "&"); //get second query
  sscanf(Token, "password=%s", password); //gets value of password field input

  Token = strtok(NULL, "&"); //get third query
  sscanf(Token, "email=%s", email); //gets value of email field input

  ePtr = email;

//decode email
  emailClean = decode(ePtr);
 printf("%s\n", *emailClean);

}
 else { printf("<p>Error: did not get a QUERY_STRING variable."); }
 }

char *decode(char *url) {
  char *emailNew;
  int i = 0;
  int y = 0;
  char current = url[i];

while(current != '%') {
   emailNew[i] = current;
   y++;
   current = url[i++];
 }
  return emailNew;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to fix your formatting; makes it easier to spot the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the malloc statement to allocate the necessary bytes and return the pointer to it in your function.

You can pass the maxsize of your string to your function as a parameter, so that you can know how many bytes to allocate. 
Or you can use another method to find the size to allocate, such as locating the first character with the value 0 (in case o C null terminated strings).

Then, just do:

```
emailNew = malloc(max_bytes);
```

Then, outside the function you can use the "free" statement to deallocate the memory you allocated with malloc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon, and please use capital letters at the start of sentences. I'm not sure how you deduce 'allocated array size is 0' from `char current = url[i];`.  I see a simple variable definition initialized to the first character of the URL string.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, you are right about the alocated array not being size 0. I'm gonna correct that, anyway i see you already gave a more complete answer. Thanks for the welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
  char *emailNew;

  /* ... */

  while(current != '%') {
     emailNew[i] = current;
     y++;
     current = url[i++];
  }
```

`emailNew` pointer is not initialized and therefore `emailNew[i] = current` assignment invokes undefined behavior.

Also:

```
 printf("%s\n", *emailClean);
```

`emailClean` is already a `char *` and `%s` requires a `char *` so you actually want to do this:

```
 printf("%s\n", emailClean);
```

I strongly suggest to enable all warnings in your compiler options and fix all the warnings.

Comment: Especially turn on warnings!

Answer (score 0):

As already diagnosed, your function `decode()` doesn't properly allocate space.

However, it also runs into another (previously undiagnosed) problem; if the email address does not contain a `%`, it goes reading extraneous memory until it finds one somewhere.  Less seriously, the variable `y` is doing nothing useful; you initialize and increment it, but never read its value.

I think the code should be written more like:

```
char *decode(char *url)
{
    char *emailNew;
    char *end = strchr(url, '%');
    if (end == 0)
        end = url + strlen(url);
    emailNew = malloc(end - url + 1);
    if (emailNew != 0)
    {
        memmove(emailNew, url, end - url);  // Or memcpy()
        emailNew[end - url] = '\0';
    }
    return emailNew;
}
```

This uses the standard C library function to find a character in a string — [`strchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strchr.html).  If it doesn't find a percent symbol, then use the whole string.  Allocate enough space; if that was successful, copy the string (which might not be null terminated) into the allocated space and null terminate the string.  Then return the data.

You could also rewrite it doing the search in your function along the lines of:

```
char *decode(char *url)
{
    char *emailNew;
    int i;
    char current;

    for (i = 0; (current = url[i]) != '%' && current != '\0'; i++)
        ;

    emailNew = malloc(i + 1);
    if (emailNew != 0)
    {
        memmove(emailNew, url, i);
        emailNew[i] = '\0';
    }
    return emailNew;
}
```